# HornetQ live lock issue

Tags: linux, jakarta-ee, hornetq

I am working on an application that uses `HornetQ` as the messaging server.On `HornetQ` start-up, I always get an error related to HornetQ live lock.

I did my research for this particular issue but have been unable to conclude on the same.

The stacktrace for this error is shown below.

```
[main] 21:09:09,516 INFO [org.hornetq.integration.bootstrap.HornetQBootstrapServer]
Starting HornetQ Server
[main] 21:09:11,208 WARNING [org.hornetq.core.deployers.impl.FileConfigurationParser]  
AIO wasn't located on this platform, it will fall back to using pure Java NIO. If your  
platform is Linux, install LibAIO to enable the AIO journal
[main] 21:09:11,283 INFO [org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl]  live server      
is starting with configuration HornetQ Configuration   
clustered=false,backup=false,sharedStore=true,journalDirectory=data/journal,bindingsDirecto     
ry=data/bindings,largeMessagesDirectory=data/largemessages,pagingDirectory=data/paging)
[main] 21:09:11,284 INFO [org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl]  Waiting to     
 obtain live lock
```

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

is that's last records in log? I see only one WARNING, related to libAIO, but it should work without it, using java NIO.